# AngularJs Avoiding Scoping Issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ngmodel

I recently spent over 4 hours before figuring out why my `ng-model` directive used in combination with `ng-options` was not correctly binding to the property within my controller. The `<select>` element was being properly initialized - receiving a value from the controller (parent) scope. But the child scope was not correctly updating the parent scope. After checking out the following questions and plunkers, I was able to develop a "work around" for this issue:

[Helpful stackoverflow question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390240/angularjs-drop-down-ng-options-not-binding-string-to-object-initial-select)

[Helpful stackoverflow question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865338/ng-model-data-is-not-binding-for-selected-ng-option)

[Basic Plunker](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/53jMp/)

I found that the property I was binding to in my `<select>` element was binding to a property of the same name within a child scope of the controller - therefore not the value was not reflected as expected in the controller's scope. After changing

```
<select ng-options="asset as asset.Name for asset in allAssets" ng-model="selectedAsset" ng-change="lookupAssetPermissions()"></select>
```

to

```
    <select ng-options="asset as asset.Name for asset in allAssets" ng-model="$parent.selectedAsset" ng-change="lookupAssetPermissions()"></select>
```

The value in `selectedAsset` was correctly binding to the property in the controller's scope (as seen in the `ng-change` event handler). The entire context of my  element is the following:

```
<!---outer div has controller level scope----->
<div>
    <!---inner div creates child scope with ng-if----->
    <div ng-if="true condition here">
        <!---select statement from above----->
        <select ng-model="$parent.selectedAsset">...</select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I have any other options in this scenario other than purposefully binding to the parent scope? If I had multiple child scopes (nested `ng-if` statements), would I need to alter the `ng-model` to bind to `$parent.$parent.$parent....selectedAsset` in order to update the value in my controllers scope? Are there any "best practices" on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all variables inside some object i.e.:

```
$scope.Model = {
  selectedAsset : 'mySelectedAsset1',
  selectedAsset2 : 'mySelectedAsset2',
  selectedAsset3 : 'mySelectedAsset3'
}
```

Then you can:

```
<div ng-repeat> //new scope
<div ng-repeat> // new scope
<input ng-model="Model.selectedAsset">
```

This also lows your 'dependency' on $scope, defining such Model object will show everyone who is reading your code what model u have.

Comment: Clean. and Functional. I've seen this solution before but did not know the advantages of its use. Thanks a lot.